# Python: splitting a string into variables

Tags: python, split

In Python how do you split a string into variables when the number of variables depends on the input string. Ex.) I want to split " (1,2,3) (2,3,4) …" into two variables (a=123 b=234)... but if more groups were inputted more variables would be created.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how to create variables when you don't know exactly how many will be made?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
>>> s="abc def"
>>> a,b=s.split()
>>> a
'abc'
>>> b
'def'
>>>
```

**Update:**

```
from string import ascii_letters as letters
s="1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
for i,v in enumerate(s.split()):
    globals()[letters[i]]=v
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)
print(f)
print(g)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: This requires knowing how many variables you're going to split the string into in advance. Definitely not a variable number of variables.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, that's right

Comment: Could someone elaborate on how to create variables when you don't know exactly how many will be made?

Comment: @NatKar Edited mine